# Desarrollo de código paso a paso en CSS

Tags: css, vba

Así como en VBA se puede hacer seguimiento paso a paso del desarrollo de cada línea de código con F8, en CSS existe la forma de ver cómo se desarrolla el código línea a línea?

Comment: boton derecho e inspeccionar o f12 en chrome te muestra las reglas css que se aplican y el orden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, al hacer clic derecho en un elemento puedes ispeccionar elemento, o tambien con F12, ahi veras las reglas aplicadas a cada elemento, incluso podras cambiarlas de forma temporal